# when the equation of position is negative its derivative is positive which is velocity which confuses me

Tags: calculus, derivatives, mathematical-physics

there is something that doesn't make sense to me
i know that Velocity is the derivative of position fine

now when i differentiate `D = T^3` i get the equation of velocity is `3T^2` which is completely okay until T is negative if t is -3

then position is -27 and velocity is 18 which is logically wrong

Comment: Why do you think it is *logically wrong*?

Comment: You really need to look at velocity as the rate of change in position. You can be anywhere, negative or positive, and be moving in the positive direction.

Comment: First, you should ask yourself *why* you think that sounds wrong.  What does a negative position have anything to do with velocity?  Let us think of an example... we have our house at the origin, and lets call "east" the positive direction.  We have a friend who is running east at a constant rate and begins west of our house.  So... he's running, and running, and eventually passes our house and keeps running east.  His velocity in this example is positive (*i.e. is running east*) at all times, including when he is currently west of the house as well as when he is eventually east of the house.

Comment: because if i am moving with 18 m/s then i should be moving forward while indeed i am moving backward

Comment: @JMoravitz but if he is moving on the opposite direction of the house then he should have his velocity negative he moving on the negative direction

Comment: i have got it @JMoravitz thanks very much really thank you

Comment: We don't talk about "moving towards the house"  we talk about "moving east" or "moving west."  We largely ignore the house when talking about velocity.  At all times, regardless of where the runner is in relation to the house he is moving east.  In your specific example, it is as though the runner slows down as he approaches the house and then speeds up again as he passes the house, but again, in both your example and mine the runner is *only* moving east (*hence a strictly non-negative velocity*).  In other examples he might change direction and move west at times.

Comment: i have been strangling to understand this but i got it now the equation is moving forward he guy who is running is moving forward so his velocity is positive

Comment: yeah i got it he is moving on the same direction no matter where he is from the origin point

Comment: really thank you man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are moving to the right but you are still on the left side of a reference point which we call it $0$

As long as you are on the left side of zero the position is negative and as long as you are moving to the right your velocity is positive.

You may as well get to the right side of the reference point and start moving to the left, which means your position is positive and your velocity is negative.

There is not confusion about it.